# Morphological extension of an image mask

Tags: image-processing

The following image is a mask derived from an imaged feature which extends to the top of the frame, but due to some lighting effects the top portion doesn't come in. Bear in mind that this is one example, and the feature moves around to some degree in each measurement.

[image]

I've been dealing with this by combining this mask with it's vertically reflected cousin:

```
mask = ImageAdd[mask,ImageReflect[FillingTransform@Erosion[mask, DiskMatrix[2]], Top]]
```

But often this feature isn't quite so symmetric in the x-direction, and sometimes appears skewed from the vertical, so this solution isn't very robust.

Is there a good way to morphologically extend the mask to the top of the image?

Comment: Your code has a typo and does not run. The brackets are not balanced.

Comment: @yohbs Thanks. Should work now.

Comment: I have addressed issues like this by Hough line/edge finding (this case L/R near vertical edges) and extending these to the top of the image and then using a measure of the edge variation to synthesize the edge "noise". This does assume that the L/R edge are supposed to be staright.

Comment: You could use `ComponentMeasurements` to get the centroid, angle and caliper width and simply draw a line with the same location, angle and thickness.

Comment: @nikie That's a clever approach. One could probably use the major axis of the best-fit ellipse for the component and draw a line from the center to the upper edge.

Comment: Exactly. Or draw a shorter line and use it as a dilation mask

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use Dilation with a tall vertical structuring element. For example:

```
mask = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/L60Yd.png"]
Dilation[Erosion[mask, 2], ConstantArray[1, {160, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this idea a lot ... sort of a directional dilation. Unfortunately, this doesn't work so well if the feature is slanted a bit, or has a non uniform width.

Comment: You can choose the dilation matrix to point in the same direction as the feature you want to dilate... so if the feature is slanted, so should be the structuring element. If you want to extract that automatically, you'd need to provide more examples.